# UDP port 3526 Starquiz-port

Tags: android, udp, sip, asterisk, wireshark

I've installed Linphone on my Galaxy S2 device and I ran tcpdump on it to capture SIP traffic that Linphone is sending to my Asterisk server. I noticed that sometimes my device sends a special packet from UDP port 3526  to my Asterisk server port (5060) that contains:

```
HEX: 0d0a0d0a
ASCII: 13101310
```

Wireshark resolves this port (UDP 3526) to starquiz-port (this name is not useful because most clients use ephemeral ports). I searched the net about this port and starquiz. The only useful information that I found is [this link at IANA](http://www.iana.org/assignments/service-names-port-numbers/service-names-port-numbers.xhtml?age=1&page=66). Does anyone know what is this packet, and why my phone is sending it to Asterisk?

PS: In [section 3.5.1 of RFC 5626](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5626#section-3.5.1) a keep-alive using CRLF is mentioned but it is only for connection oriented protocols:

> CRLF Keep-Alive Technique
> This approach can only be used with connection-oriented transports
> such as TCP or SCTP.  The client periodically sends a double-CRLF
> (the "ping") then waits to receive a single CRLF (the "pong").  If
> the client does not receive a "pong" within an appropriate amount of
> time, it considers the flow failed.

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions. Are you the developer of Linphone or Asterisk? If not, how does this question pertain to programming?

Comment: I am a Linux C developer and Android developer and I'm trying to solve an Asterisk-Linphone related problem; suddenly I came up with this packet and I became curious about it.

Answer (score 1):

You softphone can use any port.

That is normal.

Softphone or asterisk(if set qualify=yes) can send empty udp packet for keeping NATed connection active. That is also normal.

I highly recommend you read more about SIP before dooing any softphone or other sip-related programming.

Comment: I asked this question because I studied SIP RFC and as I mentioned this method is not standard! Anyway thank you.

Comment: It is not method. It just empty packet for keepalive. Pretty standart